# ¿Cómo separar dos líneas JSON?

Tags: python, json

Descargué un archivo txt que parecía un archivo JSON. Así cambié la extensión, pero no parecía ser la adecuada cuando la usé como entrada para un software que hizo. Aquí las dos primeras lineas:

```
{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?", "answer": ["Before the Rain"]}
{"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?", "answer": ["The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}
```

Aquí esta el error :

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/reader/preprocess.py", line 143, in <module>
    dataset = load_dataset(in_file)
  File "scripts/reader/preprocess.py", line 55, in load_dataset
    data = json.load(f)['data']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 88)
```

Parece que el error esta entre los dos `}{`.

Intento con una comilla `,` al final de cada lineas pero me da:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 78 (char 77)
```

Comment: Parece que falta una coma entre las dos lineas.

Comment: @alanfcm, yeah, pero entonces obtengo  `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 78 (char 77)`

Comment: Intenta encerrar todo en `[ ]`, siempre agregando las comas.

Comment: Cómo marca @alanfcm ...     [{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?", "answer": ["Before the Rain"]},
{"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?", "answer": ["The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}]

Comment: Ese archivo no es un JSON sino un simple archivo de texto donde cada línea es un JSON. Simplemente leéla línea por línea desde el lenguaje que desees.

Answer (score 2):

Como mencionan en los comentarios, no son dos líneas de un JSON más grande sino que cada línea es un JSON válido.

Si lo que quieres es pasar todo el archivo como un único JSON válido se me ocurre que puedes parsear la información y convertirlo en un solo array de objetos. Suponiendo que tengo este archivo:

```
$ cat archivo.json 
{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?", "answer": ["Before the Rain"]}
{"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?", "answer": ["The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}
```

Podemos hacer:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('archivo.json') as json_file:
...   data = '[' + ', '.join(json_file.read().strip().split('\n')) + ']'
...   print data
... 
[{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?", "answer": ["Before the Rain"]}, {"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?", "answer": ["The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}]
```

Simplemente estoy leyendo el archivo, haciendo un `strip()` para eliminar los espacios adicionales (un salto de línea al final del archivo) y haciendo un `split('\n')` para convertir cada línea en un elemento de una lista. El `', '.join(..)` es para unir cada elemento de la lista en una sola cadena de texto que represente una secuencia de objetos dentro de un array (por eso el `'['` y el `']'`).

Y ese resultado es un JSON válido, es decir, se puede convertir a un objeto en Python:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('archivo.json') as json_file:
...   data = '[' + ', '.join(json_file.read().strip().split('\n')) + ']'
...   print json.loads(data)
... 
[{u'answer': [u'Before the Rain'], u'question': u'what does Gr\xe9goire Colin appear in?'}, {u'answer': [u'The Inbetweeners Movie', u'The Inbetweeners 2'], u'question': u'Joe Thomas appears in which movies?'}]
>>>
```

Si lo que necesitas es pasar el JSON a alguna función entonces puedes pasar simplemente el contenido de `data`.

Answer (score 1):

El formato [JSON](http://json.org/) requiere tener un elemento raíz, al igual que el formato XML, pero el contenido de tu archivo representa dos objetos sin relación, que podrían ser 2 JSON distintos:

```js
const json=`
{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?","answer": ["Before the Rain"]}
{"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?","answer": [ "The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}`;

JSON.parse(json);
```

Por tanto puedes modificar ese JSON, creando un array o creando dos JSON distintos (dividiendo en dos ficheros):

```js
//opción 1 (recomendada)
const json1=`[
{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?","answer": ["Before the Rain"]},
{"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?","answer": [ "The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}]`;

console.log(JSON.parse(json1));

//opción 2 
const jsonA=`{"question": "what does Gr\u00e9goire Colin appear in?","answer": ["Before the Rain"]}`;

const jsonB=`{"question": "Joe Thomas appears in which movies?","answer": [ "The Inbetweeners Movie", "The Inbetweeners 2"]}`;

console.log(JSON.parse(jsonA));
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonB));
```

Comment: la pregunta es en relación a python....

Comment: Lo sé, pero el asunto principal es JSON, así que he usado Javascript para demostrar que lo propuesto es JSON válido de un modo práctico